# Second Y axis in GWT Highcharts on a stock chart?

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I'm trying to add a second Y axis to a StockChart with the Moxieapps Highcharts wrapper, but without success. I need to add a new axis on the right side of the chart, and would expect the following code to work:

```
StockChart chart = new StockChart();

YAxis firstYAxis = chart.getYAxis(0);
firstYAxis.setAxisTitleText("First Y axis");

Series firstSeries = chart.createSeries();
firstSeries.setPoints(/* Imagine lots of points. */);
firstSeries.setYAxis(0); // Not required since 0 is the default Y axis.

chart.addSeries(firstSeries);

YAxis secondYAxis = chart.getYAxis(1);
secondAxis.setOpposite(true); // *Should* put the axis on the right side.
secondYAxis.setAxisTitleText("Second Y axis");

Series secondSeries = chart.createSeries();
secondSeries.setPoints(/* Imagine lots of points. */);
secondSeries.setYAxis(1); // *Should* add the series to the second Y axis.

chart.addSeries(secondSeries);

// Somehow the second series ends up being in the navigator... 
chart.setOption("navigator/enabled", true);
chart.setOption("scrollbar/enabled", true);

add(chart);
```

The second Y axis does not even render. If I don't add the second series to the second Y axis, it shows up (*as expected*) as values on the first Y axis.

Has anyone successfully added **multiple Y axes on a StockChart**, that can tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Found a similar issue on the Moxieapps forum, but the solution discussed does not solve the issue: http://goo.gl/S6OhT

Comment: You should take a look highcharts demos: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes and http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

Comment: Already done that, and I've added axes to a normal StockChart. The problem lies with adding an axis with the GWT Highcharts wrapper. For example, multiple axes on a vanilla StockChart: http://jsfiddle.net/D5RQ4/

Comment: does adding a new y axis to highstock example help ?

Comment: No sorry, already managed to do that. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it seems that GWT-HighCharts is the problem. You must create YAxises manually via native calls. Here is the solution;

[HighCharts Stock Chart error code 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618155/highcharts-stock-chart-error-code-18/20633673#20633673)