# HighCharts Stock Chart error code 18

Tags: gwt, highcharts, gwt-highcharts

I am trying to add series to my chart application using gwt-highchart (using the latest gwt-highchart 1.6.0 and Highstock 2.3.4 versions). Everything seems fine until the third series. When I try to add the third one I got this error:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (String) 
@org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.BaseChart::nativeAddSeries(Lcom/google/gwt/core
/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;ZZ)([JavaScript 
object(4953), JavaScript object(5135), bool: true, bool: true]): Highcharts error #18:
www.highcharts.com/errors/18
```

And here is my code (runs within a loop):

```
            // Create a new serie with a new yAxis
        Series newSeries = chart.createSeries().setYAxis(index).setPlotOptions(new LinePlotOptions().setColor(tag.getColor()));

        // Set new yAxis options
        chart.getYAxis(index).setPlotLines(chart.getYAxis(index).createPlotLine().setValue(0).setWidth(1).setColor(tag.getColor())).setLabels(new YAxisLabels().setEnabled(false)).setTickLength(0).setOffset(60).setStartOnTick(false)
                .setEndOnTick(false).setGridLineWidth(0).setMaxPadding(DEFAULT_YAXIS_MAX_PADDING).setMinPadding(DEFAULT_YAXIS_MIN_PADDING)
                .setAxisTitle(new AxisTitle().setText(null).setStyle(new Style().setColor(tag.getColor())));

        // Add the serie to the chart
        chart.addSeries(newSeries.setName("Test " + index));
```

First two series are OK as I said before but third one throws the above exception (when I debug the application, I can see the newly created yAxis references).

Here is the line which throws the exception:

```
chart.addSeries(newSeries.setName("Test " + index));
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the chart, if you do not add 3rd series? Highcharts Error #18: The requested axis does not exist. And you are calling `.setPlotLines()` two times in the same line. Once with options, another time without. Is that ok?

Comment: Thanks @AntoJurković for your super fast comment :) If i don't add the 3rd series, it is almost fine (but sometimes i see the 2nd series in the range selection bar!) By the way, I removed the parameter-less call for `.setPlotLines()` but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out finally!

[GWT-HighCharts](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwt-highcharts/) seems to be the problem. It does not add the new YAxis to the Chart at all. So you must add YAxis via native calls like this;

```
private static native void nativeAddAxis(JavaScriptObject chart, JavaScriptObject axisOptions, boolean isX, boolean redraw, boolean animationFlag) /*-{
    chart.addAxis(axisOptions, isX, redraw, animationFlag);
}-*/;
```

Just call this native method before adding the new series.

```
            // Create new series
        Series newSeries = chart.createSeries().setYAxis(index);
        newSeries.setPlotOptions(new LinePlotOptions().setColor(tag.getColor()));
        newSeries.setName(index + 1 + ") ");

        // Create a new YAxis
        YAxis yAxis = chart.getYAxis(index).setPlotLines(chart.getYAxis(index).createPlotLine().setValue(0).setWidth(1).setColor(tag.getColor())).setLabels(new YAxisLabels().setEnabled(false)).setTickLength(0).setOffset(60)
                .setStartOnTick(false).setEndOnTick(false).setGridLineWidth(0).setPlotLines().setMaxPadding(DEFAULT_YAXIS_MAX_PADDING).setMinPadding(DEFAULT_YAXIS_MIN_PADDING)
                .setAxisTitle(new AxisTitle().setText(null).setStyle(new Style().setColor(tag.getColor())));

        // IMPORTANT!: New YAxis must be added to the chart via native calls since gwt-highcharts wrapper doesn't do that properly!
        nativeAddAxis(chart.getNativeChart(), yAxis.getOptions().getJavaScriptObject(), false, false, false);

        // Physical attach
        chart.addSeries(newSeries);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the cause of this type of errors:

If you are using [GWT-HighCharts](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwt-highcharts/) wrapper, you must make the configuration before adding chart to DOM! It seems that after adding it to the DOM, any configuration changes does not seem to work at all!

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

please check the index value.
if index is more than the axis count this error may occur

highcharts error #18 indicates that the axis trying to access does not exist.

here is the link http://www.highcharts.com/errors/18

Hope that will help you

Comment: I've checked the index values and nothing was wrong. Acutally when I debug the application, I can see the newly created YAxises in the chart instance but when i try to add the series it cannot find the associated axis (but it is there, i can see it in debug mode)